# Can a Linux computer receive scanned images from a scanner using WSD (Web Services on Devices)?

Tags: scanner

Can a Linux computer receive scanned images from a scanner using WSD (Web Services on Devices)?

**Background:**
At my work we have an Epson WP-4545 printer, and the printer part works fine from Linux, but for scanning, we can chose between "to usb-memory", or "to computer (WSD)", the 2nd option works fine with windows (borrowed a windows computer to try), but we Kubuntu and Gentoo.

1. Is there some program, or tool, that I can install to be able to receive image to the Linux computers, too?
2. Are there other names for WSD? googleing on WSD or "Web Services on Devices" didn't give much information at all.
3. Or, maybe there some other reasons for why I can't find any information, like copyright laws and patents?

Answer (score 4):

Here is your best shot:

http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

In the search:

Model: wp-4545
OS: Linux

You will be shown a list of Linux drivers for the printer and network scanner options.

```
Product Name    Category    OS  Version Module Name Language    Release Date    
WP-4545 Series    Printer Driver    Linux    latest ESC/P Driver (full feature) All language    10-12-2012  
WP-4545 Series    Printer Driver    Linux    latest ESC/P-R Driver (generic driver) All language    10-23-2012  
WP-4545 Series    Scanner Driver    Linux    Ver. 2.29.1/1.22.0 core package&data package   All language    02-12-2013  
WP-4545 Series    Scanner Driver    Linux    latest network plugin package  All language    12-21-2011
```

Answer (score 4):

[The link Wing gave](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule) is the one you want. Click over to the FAQ for details of which exactly you want for your distro, and the order to install them in (I just followed it for Linux Mint and it was painless).

Running the provided EPSON software with `iscan` won't work yet:

> "Could not send command to scanner. Check the scanner’s status."

You need to [`sudo`] edit `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf`, commenting out everything except:

```
net
epkowa
```

You'll then need to edit `/etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf` (`sudo` again) and add

```
usb
scsi
net XXX.XXX.X.X
```

where `XXX.XXX.X.X` is the IP address of your printer.

For EPSON printers this can be found by going to the Wi-fi setup on the printer interface, going to 'set manually' which shows the IP address currently in use.

**Or** easier again, you should be able to run `scanimage -L` and get a response:

```
device `epson2:net:XXX.XXX.X.X' is a Epson PID XXXX flatbed scanner
```

which upon changing of the config settings becomes:

```
device `epson2:net:XXX.XXX.X.X' is a Epson {Model} Series flatbed scanner
```

`iscan` is the program you install off the EPSON website, short for *ImageScan!*, a little GUI program for scanning. It won't load until it can find the scanner [i.e. connect to the printer] according to the configuration specified in those 2 `.conf` files.

Last tip ([again via alicious.com](http://alicious.com/iscan-linux-networked-epson/)) if you use the GIMP for graphics:

> iscan works as a plugin provided you have a link in place in the plug-ins folder:
>
> `ln -s /usr/bin/iscan /usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/iscan`

WSD, [*Web Services for Devices*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_for_Devices), is a Microsoft API, so doesn't seem like that route's accessible off-Windows as far as I can see.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same issue on an Epson initially (couldn't see my computer on the scanner). But then I just opened the Document Scan app on my machine and it worked fine. So it's not necessary to select the computer from the scanner, you can also control the scanner from the PC